# CSS inherit else?

Tags: html, css, if-statement, inheritance

I want to know if I can set a child element to

```
color: inherit;
```

but go to a different color if no color is specified in the parent element.

So I want to do the same thing you can do with font-families. ie.

```
font-family: "arial", "sans-serif";
```

So if arial is not available, it will use sans-serif.

I've tried

```
color: inherit, #646323;
```

but with no success.

Is this possible or not?

Edit 1: To explain more:

I can shorten code by doing this because I have lots of  tags on my page. Most of them I want to be custom colors (rather than the default ones (like for hover, active, visited etc). But some links, I want to be styled differently.

It would be nice to do it this way rather than using classes. Because I am editing a page that has many links on it.

Comment: The only case `inherit` could not work would be for the `:root` element. And even there, it should fallback to `initial`.

Comment: This is not possible in this way. Please explain the use case and show the HTML structure. This way people can come up with suggestions how to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: *"It would be nice to do it this way rather than using classes."* - If you want some styling to always be in a certain way, but occasionally in a different way, then use CSS classes. Those are the idiomatic way for solving this problem, and they are semantically better than your "role reversal": Currently you are trying to express *"it should inherit, but most of the time there is nothing to inherit, so it should use a fallback value"*. That's defining an exception as the default. Make the fallback value the default and override where necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea is to consider CSS variable for this:

```css
p {
  color: var(--c); /*initial is the fallback if --c is not defined */
}

span {
  color: var(--c, red); /*red is the fallback if --c is not defined*/
}
```

```html
<p>
  color <span>text</span>
</p>
<p style="--c:blue">
  color <span>text</span>
</p>
```